# A ticket System to integrate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ticket-system

I want to add a Ticket System to the web app I'm developing.

The idea is very simple:
Users can open tickets when they have problems and 
the Admin can see the tickets the users have submitted.

I'm looking for a ticket system but I have found only systems that are external to the web. I want to add it IN my wep app.

¿Do you know any ticket system por rails?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think using some external gem like noted above would be either an overkill or a hassle due to mentioned bad documentation.

Judging by your problem description this is quite simple to implement.

- Create model for tickets and associations with users (I assume you
  already have users model fully set up).
- Authorize access to tickets' actions depending on user status (admin
  or not)
- Create corresponding views

P.S.
You could have a look at [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) code. It is an open source project management software written in rails. I am sure this could give you a good idea of how to build your own or even borrow bits of code from there (if the app license that you are building fits)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Simple-Ticket](https://github.com/gdeflaux/Simple-Ticket) would fit you. Though beware the basic implementation and the fact that there is no documentation provided nor written specs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [restrospectiva](https://github.com/dim/retrospectiva). It doesn't have any documentation though